# Unable to display the UI of the xml in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I can't seem to display or view the  UI of my xml inside layout-land-1208x752 folder but in the other folder, it's showing properly.

[image]

I have read similar issue in Stack Overflow but none of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's  work on my end  please check your xml file or update ADT.

Answer (score 0):

To update your ADT, go to Help -> Install new software and add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ as repository

or if you have already done it try to check updates from eclipse